# CSS: Add same height to sibling children

Tags: css

I have this situation, with two seperated card components, and it is nesseserly to add both headings same height.

Is it possible using only CSS?

[image]

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__head">
    <h4 class="heading4 c-white">
      Heading
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="card__body">
    <p class="paragraph">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque quis commodo mauris.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want the blue header to be adjusted based on the height of the gray header, you need javascript.

Comment: you can use css flex properties for achieving this .

Answer (score 1):

simple no by pure css you can not do this. you have to put fixed height which is not feasible. best way to go is matchHeight js and using `display:inline-block; and vertical-align:middle`.

1) you apply div **structure and css** according to codepen using inline-block. keep in mind that both title are in different columns

```
    <div class="fa-title"><h4>heading 1</h4></div>
        <div class="fa-title"><h4>heading 2</h4></div>
<style>
.fa-title{text-align:center;}
.fa-title h4{display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;}
.fa-title h4::before,
.fa-title h4::after{content:""; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; height:100%; white-space:nowrap;}
</style>
```

2) apply js to that div for common height of both div.

```
`$('.fa-title').mathcHeight();`
```

http://brm.io/jquery-match-height-demo/

https://codepen.io/edge0703/pen/iHJuA

Answer (score -3):

You want same height heading and if title is bigger then you need to hide overflow title text part using css.

You can use this css properties for heading section:

```
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: Hi Shyam. Please include the code within your answer. Link-only answers will tend to be down voted and/or deleted. Thanks.